# How to write a program in C which reads a word from the user and terminates if the user enters the word "exit"?

Tags: c

Here is the code that I wrote.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char wd[100];

do
{
printf(">");
fgets(wd,100,stdin);
}while(strcmp(wd,"exit")!=0);

}
```

When I run this, it reads words repeatedly from me, it doesnot terminate even if I eneter "exit". Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` will store new-line character `'\n'` if it exists, so remove it before compareing.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void chomp(char *str)
{
    char *lf = strchr(str, '\n');
    if (lf != NULL) *lf = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    char wd[100];

    do
    {
        printf(">");
        fgets(wd,100,stdin);
        chomp(wd);
    }while(strcmp(wd,"exit")!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is giving the output.